In SharePoint 2019, query suggestions are not automatically created
We are currently using SharePoint 2019. Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/create-and-import-query-suggestions say Sharepoint automatically creates a query suggestion when you have clicked a search result for a query at least six times or if I  want to display query suggestions immediately, I could import the suggested phrase from a text file.
I already imported a query and it is working fine. My concern is we also want to have an automatic query suggestion if it clicks 6 times but it is not working as expected. I already removed the query I imported to test if it will work if no default suggest phrase is set but it still doesn't work
Can anyone confirm if this feature is only for SharePoint Online or are there any other configurations, I need to set up in SP2019?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I updated the question. Let me know if the details are already sufficient.
